# Deluge- how to prevent a user who is already signed in from signing in again

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I have written a simple deluge script for a Sign In app.
Is there a way to prevent a user who is already signed in from signing in again?
Likewise, is there a way to prevent a user who is already signed out from signing out again?
What I have below populates the Staus with either Sign In or Sign Out but the user can manually override this is and sign In/Out twice

```
var = Sign_in_out[UserName == input.UserName] sort by Added_Time Desc;
if(var.Status == "Sign In")
{
    Status.select("Sign Out");
}
else if(var.Status == "Sign Out")
{
    Status.select("Sign In");
}
else
{
    Status.select("Sign In");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Zoho-Creator, the login state of a user can be checked with either `zoho.loginuser` or `zoho.loginuserid`.  If either of these is  `null` then the user is logged out.  If they are not-null, then the user is logged in.

Deluge probably has the same  behavior in other Zoho tools, but give it a try in-order to verify the behavior.

Example:

```
if (zoho.loginuserid == null)
{
    info "Login-Status: Signed-Out:[" + zoho.loginuserid + "]";
}
else
{
    info "Login-Status: Signed-In:[" + zoho.loginuserid + "]";
}
```

**10-26-2022, Additional note after comments:**

Try automatically refreshing the page. Here is a few example methods. These methods should work for Pages, Forms and Reports.

Example:

```
// Refresh a page using a full path url
openUrl("https://<zoho-url-path/#Page:<page-name>", "same window");

// Refresh a form with Zoho short path
openUrl("#Form:<login-form-name>", "same window");
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem I am having. Users can still sign out twice instead of just once.

Comment: Is the second sign-out happening on the same browser tab?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same tab.

Comment: Okay, I added a 'refresh' suggestion to my response based on our comment exchange.